# Remove element from every list in a column in pandas dataframe based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to remove values in list from column B based on column A, wondering how.

Given:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
    'B': [['a1', 'a2'], ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], ['a1', 'a3'], []]
})
```

I want:

```py
result = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
    'B': [['a1', 'a2'], ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], ['a1', 'a3'], []],
    'Output': [['a2'], ['a1', 'a3'], ['a1'], []]
})
```

Comment: How so? What is the logic of `"based on column A"` and what have you tried so far?

Comment: At the index 0 the output column in df2 shows that, a1 is removed from column B based on a1 in column A.  Similarly for all rows, the corresponding value in column A is removed from column B. If column B is empty then it would be empty.

Comment: df.B.apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i != list(df.A)])

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of doing that is applying a filtering function to each row via [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['Output'] = df.apply(lambda x: [i for i in x.B if i != x.A], axis=1)
```

Comment: With a comprehension instead of `apply`: `df.assign(Output=[[z for z in x if z != y] for x, y in zip(df.B, df.A)])`

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using `iterrows()`:

```
for i,value in df.iterrows():
    try:
        value['B'].remove(value['A'])
    except ValueError:
        pass
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    A         B
0  a1      [a2]
1  a2  [a1, a3]
2  a3      [a1]
3  a4        []
```